# Windows 8.1 Create Custom Toolbar Widgets?

Tags: windows, widget, windows-8.1, taskbar

I have a need to regularly search our internal directory for colleagues across the organisation (30k people). It's slow and irritating to launch even a shortcut to the intranet directory.

What I'd like to do is create a custom 'widget' (might be the wrong word) on my Windows 8.1 taskbar which is just a text box and a search button. This would then launch a browser with a HTTP POST url which will have my query in the URL.

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how to create a custom taskbar app/widget.

Any ideas where I can find the documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

A [deskband](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx) will do.But Microsoft's recommendation is [don't create new deskbands , write thumbnail toolbars instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762064(v=vs.85).aspx). If you go with write thumbnail toolbars, you can create an enter text button and a search button, register with ITaskbarList3::ThumbBarAddButtons, and create a textbox when the enter text button is clicked for the text editing.

You can also integrate with Windows search by [writing a web service that integrates with Windows Federated Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940452(v=vs.85).aspx). But this uses Windows Explorer's search box and your data there could be pollution to the user when they search for something else.